# How to serialize XML with collections of nodes using Xml Attributes

Tags: c#, xml-serialization, xmlserializer, xml-attribute

I'm trying to serialize Xml using the **XmlSerializer** and by using its attributes.
My problem is that I'm not getting the data of the **EVENT** items.
I'm not fully aware of how to treat the combination between **EVENTSCOLLECTION** and **EVENT** by using the attributes (**XmlRoot** and **XmlElement** - should I use **XmlArray** ?)
I'm getting the **EventsCollection** with 0 items. I would rather get rid of the **EventsCollection** class - it is there just because I don't know how to use the  combination.
This is my XML:

```
<MSGDATA>
    <EVENTSCOLLECTION>
        <EVENT>
            <Id>1</Id>
            <EventNumber>100</EventNumber>
        </EVENT>
        <EVENT>
            <Id>2</Id>
            <EventNumber>200</EventNumber>
        </EVENT>
        <EVENT>
            <Id>3</Id>
            <EventNumber>300</EventNumber>
        </EVENT>
    </EVENTSCOLLECTION>
</MSGDATA>
```

This is the data structure:

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName="EVENT")]
public class EventItem
{
    [XmlElement("Id")]
    public int ID {get; set;}
    
    [XmlElement("EventNumber")]
    public int EventNumber {get; set;}
}

//I would get rid of it if I could find a way
[XmlRoot(ElementName="EVENTSCOLLECTION")]
public class EventsCollection
{
    private List<EventItem> eventItems
    public List<EventItem> EventItems
    {
        get
        {
            if (eventItems == null)
            {
                eventItems = new List<EventItem>();
            }
            return eventItems;
        }
        set
        {
            eventItems = value;
        }
    }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName="MSGDATA")]
public class EventMsgData
{
    [XmlElement("EVENTSCOLLECTION")]
    //I would replace this propery with a property with a type of List<EventItem> if I would know how to combine it with the XML attributes 
    private EventsCollection events;
    public EventsCollection Events { get; set;  }
}
```

This is How I try to serialize it:

```
XmlSerializer xmls = new XmlSerialized(typeof(EventMsgData));
EventMsgData result = (EventMsgData)xmls.Deserialize(new StringReader(<text of MSGDATA xml node>))
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by doing these changes:

1. I removed the EventsCollection class - it isn't needed.
2. I've used the attributes:

   [XmlArray("EVENTSCOLLECTION")]

   [XmlArrayItem("EVENT")]

in the EventMsgData class, as shown below:

```
[XmlArray("EVENTSCOLLECTION")]
[XmlArrayItem("EVENT")]
public List<EventItem> EventItems
```